# Linux. No such file or directory, хотя папка существует

Tags: nginx, linux-mint

root@root-xxxxxx:/home$ cd /root
bash: cd: /root: No such file or directory

Linux Mint работает на Nginx. Раньше все работало правильно, сейчас выходит такая ошибка. Хотя такая директория существует, и раньше открывалась. До этого пришлось копаться в настройках nginx, может быть там что-то слетело. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно испарвить,если кто знает. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

У пользователя, который запускает Ngnix, нет прав на чтение папки /root.